# Why does my user-defined Babel shorthand containing tipa not work?

Tags: babel, tipa, shorthands

Why does this not work?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\useshorthands*{:}
\defineshorthand{:a}{a\textipa{:}}

\begin{document}

Some text. :a Some more text.

\end{document}
```

The code shows as:

[image: The ":a" sequence is output as a with a paragraph immediately following.]

and the log gives

> Argument of \user@active@arg: has an extra }. :a 
>   Paragraph ended before \user@active@arg: was complete. :a

The culprit seems to be the \textipa{:}, because it works fine if I take it out of the shorthand, but shouln't it be possible to have code within the definition of a shorthand? And why does Latex give me a paragaph here at all?

(The \textipa command is from the tipa package and \textipa{:} should only insert a phonetic length symbol.)

Comment: Can you please make a full (minimal) example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Yep, sorry about that.

Comment: Actually, the problem seems to be more on tipa's side than on babels, considering that, for exampe, \textit{:} works perfectly fine. Maybe the Font switch does something bad here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use an active `:` in the replacement text:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\useshorthands*{:}
\defineshorthand{:a}{a\textipa{\string:}}

\begin{document}

Some text. :a Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So as a general rule, never use a character defined as shorthand within a shorthand macro (unless intended as shorthand?) I was convinced babel would realise that it isn't intended to be a shorthand, since it wasn't part of any defined shorthand there.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind my asking, where do I find out what exactly the \string command does? I tried googling "latex string" and am now scarred for life.

Comment: @thisismynamenow `\string` is a TeX primitive that makes the following token into a string (category code 12). For reasons I don't really understand, `babel` makes immediately `:` an active character, contrary to what happens to other shorthand characters. But `\string:` is essentially the same as “the normal colon”.